# Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline not recognizing " jobs: " or " stages: " tag/names, as documented in the usable syntax

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an **azure-pipelines.yml** controlling my build etc... works ok.

However I seem to be restricted, I can not use jobs: or stages: as documented in their allowable syntax for describing pipelines when editing the pipeline within the online editor.

[image: Intellisence in online editor]

In the above image no matter what or where I type, I do not get access to jobs, stages...

documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema

how can I get access to these keywords as documented?

Comment: Can you reproduce your YAML file for us? You can share the online YAML editor link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the syntax in the screenshot, `steps` is defined in your yaml. Remove the `steps` and the `stages` should be displayed normally. `steps` should be under `job` level and `jobs` need to be under the `stage` level.

[image]

Please refer to the Pipeline structure in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-structure):

[image]

Comment: stages: does not appear in the intellisense, not even at the top, I have schedules, services and strategy to choose from. That's all the legal options.

Comment: It seems that `steps` is defined in your yaml. Remove the `steps` and the `stages` should be displayed normally. `steps` should be under `job` level.

Comment: @Choco Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether the answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Comment: @ Hugh Lin... Yes the comment is right, if "steps:" is added anywhere, it affects the yaml even before "steps:" is used, I assume the web interface does a full parse and makes some strange assumptions on the use of defaults. can you update your answer to include this and I can mark as solution. :-)

Comment: @Choco Thanks for your note. I update the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below structure to configure your azure-pipelines.yml.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Building!
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: TestOnWindows
    steps:
    - script: echo Testing on Windows!
  - job: TestOnLinux
    steps:
    - script: echo Testing on Linux!
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - script: echo Deploying the code!
```